# HttpServletRequest.getParameterValues oddity in tomcat 6 and tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, servlets

Has anyone come across this oddity with the servlet-api shipped with Tomcat 6 and Tomcat 7?

In Tomcat 6 `HttpServletRequest.getParameterValues` returns the internal array of parameter values. In tomcat 7 it returns a copy.

Now the problem is that if your code pulls the parameter values out into an array and modifies the array, like so

```
String[] params = m_request.getParameterValues(property);
.
.
.
// do some operations that modify params.
```

the internal array gets modified so if you pull the array out again its changed !!

in Tomcat 7 this is not the case, you get a copy of the array instead of direct access to the internal one. Just wondering if anyone can testify to this being the case ...